# Test for weak instruments in Stata when using VCE robust

Tags: stata, instrumental-variables, robust-standard-error, 2sls

does anyone know how I can test for weak instruments (one instrument, just identified model) after 2SLS regression in Stata when using robust standard errors (VCE robust)?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ivreg2` like this:

```
use https://www.stata-press.com/data/r16/hsng
ivreg2 rent pcturban (hsngval = faminc i.region), robust
```

This reports the robustified Kleibergen-Paap Wald rk F statistic.

There is also `twostepweakiv`, which has different tests.

Both commands are available from SSC.

Comment: Thanks! Can I compare the Kleibergen-Paap Wald rk F statistic to the common Stock & Yogo threshold of 10? I.e., if Kleibergen-Paap Wald rk F statistic > 10, then this is one indication that the instrument is not weak?

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, there are no papers that derive the critical values for using the Kleibergen-Paap statistic. Some people will still use the iid CVs. Other will rely on the F statistic being at least 10, like you suggest.

Comment: See p.490 of [this SJ paper](https://journals.sagepub.com/doi/pdf/10.1177/1536867X0800700402).